# servicestack .netcore cannot resolve package

Tags: servicestack, .net-core

I am trying to open a .net core solution with servicestack dependencies, and for every servicestack dependency I am getting the message "The dependency ServiceStack.Core>=1.0.* could not be resolved".

Here is my project.json

```
{
"version": "1.0.0-*",

"dependencies": {
"NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
"ServiceStack.Client.Core": "1.0.*",
"ServiceStack.Common.Core": "1.0.*",
"ServiceStack.Core": "1.0.*",
"ServiceStack.Interfaces.Core": "1.0.*",
"ServiceStack.Redis.Core": "1.0.*",
"ServiceStack.Text.Core": "1.0.*"
},

"frameworks": {
  "netstandard1.6": {
    "imports": "dnxcore50"
  }
 }
}
```

I have installed ServiceStackVS tools into Visual Studio using the following link: http://docs.servicestack.net/create-your-first-webservice

I am not sure how to get the actual assemblies that are being referenced

Comment: Do you get the same message if you are trying to Restore the Packages?

Comment: Yes I do............

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ServiceStack.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Core) NuGet package is published on NuGet so if you're having issues resolving it you should check to make sure you have the [latest version of NuGet](https://dist.nuget.org/index.html) installed and that your NuGet Package Sources (Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager) includes an entry for nuget.org to:

```
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

---

Note: ServiceStackVS and the [create your first web service](http://docs.servicestack.net/create-your-first-webservice) documentation only has support for creating .NET 4.5 Framework projects.

The best way to create a ServiceStack .NET Core project currently is to start with a copy of one of the [.NET Core Live Demos](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/LiveDemos), e.g. The [.NET Core Hello repository](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/Hello/tree/master/src) has an empty project template for 3 common scenarios:

- Mvc (ServiceStack + Razor + ASP.NET MVC Core)
- Web App (ServiceStack WebApp)
- SelfHost (ServiceStack SelfHost)

In future ServiceStack's .NET Core Templates will be through the new `dotnet new` template support which is currently being developed in [NetCoreApps/templates](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/templates)

Comment: I get the same problem on the sample. For example in the SelfHost project there are errror lines "the dependency cannot be resolved" for each of the references except for Microsoft.NetCore.App

Comment: @jazza1000 the packages are restoring fine for me. I'd check to make sure you have the latest version of NuGet installed and your NuGet Package Sources (Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager) include `nuget.org / https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`

Comment: Cheers Mythz, setting the nuget source has fixed all my problems, if you want to add this as an answer, or edit your post, I will accept it